# Book where aliens destroy the moon to deny humans access to space?

Tags: story-identification, novel

For the life of me I can't remember this series of books.  Humanity sends an expedition to negotiate with an alien race, and they discover that humanity's been building a fleet in secret so they turn off all electricity on Earth, and ultimately destroy the moon to deny humans access to space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[**Earthbound**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11407995-earthbound)" by Joe Halderman.

The blurb mentions a group of aliens (the "others") feeling threatened by Earth's fleet:

> The mysterious alien Others have prohibited humans from space
>   travel-destroying Earth's fleet of starships in a display of
>   unimaginable power. Now Carmen Dula, the first human to encounter
>   Martians and then the mysterious Others, and her colleagues struggle
>   to find a way, using nineteenthcentury technology, to reclaim the
>   future that has been stolen from them.

and the review below mentions the destruction of the moon and the disablement of electronic devices:

> The story begins a few days after the group that was out to visit The
>   Others, returns to an Earth on which 50 years have passed, and The
>   Others have smashed the moon and disabled all electromechanical
>   devices. Seriously, this book should have started with a synopsis of
>   the earlier two books.

[image]

Comment: Ok god that's it, *sigh of relief*, thank you!

Comment: Beat me to the punch. I'll just mention this is the third book in a trilogy called the **Marsbound Trilogy**- the previous two books are **Marsbound** and **Starbound**.